# How to show $\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k))<\frac{1}{k \ln(k)},\forall K\in \mathbb{N}, K\geq 2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I show the inequality $\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k))<\dfrac{1}{k\ln(k)},\forall K\in \mathbb{N}, K\geq 2.$

Answer (score 2):

From Mean value theorem we have,
$$\displaystyle\frac{\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k))}{k+1-k}=\frac{1}{\ln c}.\frac{1}{c},c\in(k,k+1)$$
$$k<c\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\ln c}.\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{\ln k}.\frac{1}{k}$$
$$\Rightarrow\displaystyle{\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k))}=\frac{1}{\ln c}.\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{\ln k}.\frac{1}{k}$$
$$\Rightarrow\displaystyle{\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k))}<\frac{1}{\ln k}.\frac{1}{k}$$
We are done.

Comment: Thank for your you valuable time. Now it is okay.

Comment: By the way is it possible to show $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(ln(ln(k+1))-ln(lnk))=\infty$ so that by comparison test $\sum_{K=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{klnk}$ also divergent?

Comment: I guess yes@user61455

Comment: Another test which you can use $\sum a_i$ is convergent if and only if $\sum 2^ka_{2^k}$ is convergent.